# Stream (pointer to a file structure) in File handling giving strange values

Tags: c++, filestream, fopen, file-handling, fputs

i am trying to output a buffer to a file using visual c++.
my code for doing it is-

```
FILE *stream;

stream=fopen("C:\\Users\\sshekha\\Desktop\\z.txt","r");

//I also tried with "w" mode
//the differencein behavious on executing these two is that when it is in read mode it 
//executes the else condition in the code below whereas in "w" mode it executes the "if"
// condition, 
//moreover even if i change the path it don't execute the "else" condition-that means this path
//is effective to the code. and  the another surprising thing is when i open the file manually
// and then run the code with "r" mode it still executes the "else" part (which it shouldn't
// because the file is already open.) 

if( stream == 0 )
{
    MessageBox(m_hwndPreview,L" the file is not opened ",L"BTN WND",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(m_hwndPreview,L" the file is opened ",L"BTN WND",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    int check=fputs (HtmlFileContents,stream);
    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to check the results using different mode in order to understand whats teh probem going on . when i debug it , i get the value of (in Read mode) :

> stream = 0x000000005c5c76f0 { _ptr=0x0000000000000000  _cnt=0 _base=0x0000000000000000  ...}

I don't know it gib=ves bad pointer and even then it go to else part of the loop. Why ?

and in write mode

> stream = 0x0000000000000000 {_ptr=??? _cnt=??? _base=??? ...}

So go to the if part of the loop.

Moreover  my path is correct and i have enough permission to do the task I wish. But why does it give bad pointer ? Why have I these strange values of stream and what should I do to copy the content of my buffer `HtmlFileContents` in to `z.txt` ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You're opening the file in read-only mode and writing to it. That's your problem.

Comment: No i done that just to explain you the behaviour in different modes(w/r). in "w" mode it go to the if loop (i mean stream returns zero) whereas in "r" mode it go to second loop that means the stream has some contents but it has some <bad ptr> you can see above . why it do so ?? and why the control don't go to else condition when the mode is "w" ??

Comment: "r" is definitely the wrong mode. Have you tried "w+"?

Comment: Vite i hqve done it ..the control go to "if" condition when i do this. i mean stream returns zero in this  case.

Comment: Can you also let us know which compiler you're using? I'm assuming Visual C++ but which version?

Comment: visual c++ 2010 . i don't know which compiler it contains i am working first time on visual studio but its not a consolle application its a Mfc appliucation. If still you want to know then could you please tellme how to check the compiler in visual studio ??

Comment: Please try the suggestion in my answer.

Comment: sorry couldn't understand you?????which suggestion ??? i am using visual studio 2010 . and i am trying to do my task since last morning and still not able to find the problem . i feel thayt the code is rigth there is some other  problem.

Comment: Use `perror` to print the cause of error or `strerror()` to retrieve the error message and display it using `MessageBoxA(m_hwndPreview,"Failed to open file because...", errorCause);`. See my edits in my answer on how to use `perror` and `strerror`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34136/discussion-between-vite-falcon-and-shekhar-singh-shekhawat)

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in read-only mode: `fopen("C:\\Users\\sshekha\\Desktop\\z.txt","r");`. Here `"r"` says you only intend to read from file. To be able to write contents (i.e. `fputs(...)`), open the file in write mode like so: fopen("C:\Users\sshekha\Desktop\z.txt","w")`(or`"a"` if you want to append). For more information, [read fopen documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

EDIT: I see that you've tried both read and write modes. You're code only shows read-mode and hence my assumption on the read-only problem. Let me do a bit more research and get back.

Please write the following code in your `if` statement:

`perror("The following error occurred:");`

if you don't have a console, use this to store the error string:

`char* errorCause = strerror(errno); MessageBoxA(m_hwndPreview, errorCause, "BTN WND", MB_ICONINFORMATION);`

and let us know what you see as the cause.

EDIT 2: Since you've mentioned that you're using Visual Studio 2010, are you running it as yourself? This stackoverflow answer shows that VS2010 has different options when debugging applications; https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704942/210634

NOTE: That feature is only available on 'Pro' versions.

Here's a working example: https://ideone.com/hVLgc4

Comment: i think you haven't read the question properly please see the lines "whereas in "w" mode it executes the "if"  condition,".

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT: Yup. I have that part on my 'EDIT' section.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is "read only", opening with it with write permissions should fail.

to see if that is the case,under windows:

- right click the file
- press properties
- at the bottom, see if "Read-only" attribute i marked with "v"
  (uncheck it if you desire writing to the file)

refer to :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx

on how to change file permissions from your code