# "Debug As" in VS2012 web project?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, credentials

I have Visual Studio 2012.  My laptop is not on our company domain (BYOD).  I have Visual Studio configured to "Run As" my domain account.  I have configured my project to use IIS Express and have set it to "Windows Authentication".  However, when I run the project and it launches Chrome, it's using my local credentials.  I need it to use my domain credentials.

I found this SO [RunAs A different user when debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287099/runas-a-different-user-when-debugging-in-visual-studio) which looks pretty good, but it refers to VSCommands 2010.  I downloaded VSCommands for 2012 and cannot find the "Debug As" option anywhere in the settings (or in the debug menu).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm VSCommands developer, this option should be available in context menu on web project (expand 'debug' group). If it isn't, please let me know on Jarek@squaredinfinity.com more about the project type (e.g. mvc 4, c# etc). thanks!

Comment: You're right, it is available.  I was looking for it on the top menu... Thanks!