# How to run the console application after build using different user in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to ask if there is settings at **Visual Studio 2010** wherein, the console application can be ran using different user? Because I want to debug and run the console using a different user.

thanks!

Comment: not the visual studio itself to run as different user but only the console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287099/runas-a-different-user-when-debugging-in-visual-studio. You can also just launch the console app with `RunAs` and then `attach to process` in VS Debugger.