# VS2019 debugging as different user with runas, but won't stop at breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, runas

I'm trying to debug a program using a different user then my own in order to have special permissions. I'm using the Start External Program functionality in order to start runas.exe.

This part goes well and I can start the program successfully, however the program will not stop at any of my breakpoints in the code, even though it is supposed to be running in debug mode. The breakpoints work fine when I run the program normally as my own user. Does anybody have any ideas why this is not working?

My configuration:

[image]

Comment: You're debugging runas.exe, not the process that it starts.  Having to use Debug > Attach is clumsy, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923052/17034).

Comment: No the runas.exe is just a program you run in order to be able to supply different credentials for execution. The problem with the solution you suggest is the user i want to use has to have a visual studio license in order to work, which it unfortunetly doesn't.