# How to debug run a project as a different user in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I need to debug run a C# project using a different user. I found [this link](https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-launch-different-user/), However, it's old.

How do you debug a project as a different user in Visual Studio 2022?

The `Launch Profiles` doesn't have the executable field.
[image: Launch Profiles]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RunAs A different user when debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287099/runas-a-different-user-when-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Comment: No, I want to using the approach of the link, for visual studio 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean how to using the approach for a .net core project, here is the steps:

1. Click the downward arrow in the picture and choose "<project> Debug Properties".

[image: Step1]

2. In the dialog click the first button and choose "Executable".

[image: Step2]

3. Input the executable and arguments.
4. Select the new profile (in the first picture) and start debugging.
5. Note that with this approach you still need attach to the process, see the comments in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287221/6196568

Comment: I didn't see the first field in my Visual Studio 2022. It starts with `Command line arguments` in my Visual Studio?

Comment: You need create a new **Executable** profile, a Project profile starts with "Command line arguments"